# Kendo.UI Grid Change row color on hover

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a Kendo Grid declared inside of a Kendo Splitter like this in my partial view.

```
@(Html.Kendo().Splitter()
  .Name("adminSplitter")
  .Orientation(SplitterOrientation.Horizontal)

  .Panes(p =>
             {
                 p.Add()
                    .HtmlAttributes(new
                                            {
                                                id = "adminLeftHandPane"
                                            })
                    .Resizable(false)
                    .Size("150px")
                    .Content(@<text>
                                @(Html.Kendo().Grid<AdministrativeTask>()
                                    .Name("grdAdminTasks")
                                    .ClientRowTemplate("<tr class=\"gridRow\"><td style=\"cursor:pointer\"><img src=\"#=ImageUrl#\" style=\"height: 16px; width: 16px;\" />&nbsp;#=Title#</td></tr>")

                                    .Columns(c => c.Bound(i => i.Action)
                                                   .Title("Administrative Tasks"))
                                    .Selectable(s => s.Mode(GridSelectionMode.Single))
                                    .DataSource(ds => ds.Ajax().Read("LoadAdministrativeTasks", "Admin").ServerOperation(false))
                                    .Events(e => e.Change("change"))
                                )
                            </text>);
                 p.Add()

                    .HtmlAttributes(new
                                            {
                                                id = "adminRightHandPane"
                                            })
                    .Content(@<text>
                                  <div id="adminRightHandPaneContent"></div>
                              </text>)
                                            ;
             }
  )

  )
```

and in this same partial view my script looks like this

```
<script>
function change() {
    var row = this.select();
    var item = this.dataItem(row);

    $.ajax({
        url: '/' + item.Controller + '/' + item.Action,
        contentType: 'application/html; charset=utf-8',
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'html',
        cache: false,
    })
                .success(function (result) {
                    // Display the section contents.
                    $('#adminRightHandPaneContent').html(result);
                })
                .error(function (xhr) {
                    $('#adminRightHandPaneContent').html("ERROR: <br><br>" + xhr.responseText);
                    //alert(xhr.responseText);
                });

}


$(document).ready(function () {
    alert($('.gridRow'));
    $(".gridRow").hover(

   function () {
       alert("hit");
       $(this).addClass("highlightRow");
   },
        function() {
            $(this).removeClass("highlightRow");
        }

 );
});
```

When the partial view loads I get the alert "[object Object]" which tells me that Jquery found the row. However, when I hover over the row in question I do not get the "hit" alert message so at this point I am at a loss on how to proceed.

I am trying to get the row highlighted when the user hovers over the row. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you just want to change the styling of a row when the cursor is over the row of table, you can simply define a CSS style as:

```
#grid tbody tr:hover {
    background: #ff0000;
}
```

Where `grid` is the `id` of the grid.

See if running here http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/uN2W5/

So you don't even need to add a CSS classes, hover function handlers,...

Comment: OnaBai: it didn't work. here's what I put "#grdAdminTasks tbody tr:hover {background: #ffdc87;}", and still nothing happens.

Comment: Does the jsfiddle that I put in my answer work for you? If so, we can work in the differences with your page.

Comment: Yes, the jsFiddle Link works I can see the rows changing color. it just didn't work for my page. I wonder if it is because is way nested in divs(from the splitter then into the grid).

Comment: Shouldn't since the identifier (`#grdAdminTask`) is the identifier of the grid and the rest of the structure is generated by KendoUI. BTW: Which version of KendoUI are you using? If is different than v2012.3.1114 can you try with this?

Comment: For some reason it was caching the old CSS hence I didn't see the change, I restarted Visual Studio Several times and still didn't work, it wasn't until I rebooted my machine when it worked.

Comment: Any thoughts on getting it working on a grid with locked/frozen columns? I guess it would require some (simple) JS, right?

Comment: Edit: I create the JS for doing this with frozen columns. Seems inefficient though... http://jsfiddle.net/dmathisen/wptr3gu0/

Answer (score 8):

in generic form:

```
.k-grid table tr:hover td {
background :rgb(107, 188, 242) !important;
cursor: pointer !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

in Q1 2016 
kendo ui has in the css this line

```
.k-grid tr:hover{background-image:url(textures/highlight.png);background-image:none,-webkit-gradient(linear,left top,left bottom,from(rgba(255,255,255,.45)),to(rgba(255,255,255,0)));background-image:none,-webkit-linear-gradient(top,rgba(255,255,255,.45) 0,rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%);background-image:none,linear-gradient(to bottom,rgba(255,255,255,.45) 0,rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%);background-color:#88c5e0}
```

so it should work out of the box

Comment: This explained to me why the demo had this behavior but my older version did not

Answer (score 0):

```
.k-grid table tr.k-state-selected{background: red;color: black; }
```

Comment: the selection works fine, it has a dark blue color when someone clicks on a row, the problem I am having is when a user hovers over the row, I want it to change color.

Comment: .k-grid table tr:hover {
    background:orange;
}

Comment: it'd would also be nice to remove the hover style if the row already has the selected style...

Comment: You can do this using Jquery !!

Comment: @tote: you can do that with CSS too: `tr:hover:not(.k-state-selected) { ... }`